# Header is messed up in IE 7-8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout, header

The page I am working on is displaying perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari (in both Mac and Windows) except in **IE 7 & 8**. The header is suppose to look like this:
[image]

but in IE it appears like this:
[image]

before we were using `position: relative;` for our class `container` in our `charity.css` file, but i had to remove that as it was creating problems in IE w/ my drop-down menus.

Can someone PLEASE help me?! I am so out of ideas now :(

Here is the [**page**] (however, i would have to remove the link later)  Any help will be highly appreciated!!

**Edited:** here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/walahh/QwFL6/ it's not exactly the same page...but hopefully you will get the idea.

Comment: Please check your site at http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zionsdirect.com%2Fcharity%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 (though that's not the cause of the problem here)

Comment: Please distill your HTML and CSS into a simplified test case and post on http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar site. This site is meant to help everyone, and if your link disappears later, it will help no one (except yourself).

Comment: @PezCuckow: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll do that :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: i agree w/ you, let me finish this problem, then may be before removing the link i'll post the code on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the fix was pretty simple....i was making it way too complicated.

What I (also) didn't know was "In IE the z-index can not be higher than the contain element's z-index."

So I went back to the original file, where they had `.container{width:940px; margin:0 auto; position: relative;}` and left it as it is. Then added z-index values for the `#header{.....; z-index:1; }` and `#mainNav{...; z-index:2;}` And that took care of the...

- hidden drop-down menu(s)
- messed up header

here is the modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/walahh/QwFL6/3/

hope this helps someone :) and thank you everyone who took their time to read my post and help me.

Answer (score 1):

The only change I can think of would cause a somewhat significant change in your markup.

Basically, I'm pretty sure that this has to do with `float:left` and `float:right` elements not being cleared.  IE is notorious for incorrectly propagating the float property to elements which weren't intended to be floated.  To avoid this - when floating - it is common to do something like this...

CSS:

```
.fl { float: left; }
.fr { float: right; }
.clr { clear: both; }
```

And then doing this in your markup:

```
<div>
  <div class="fl"></div> 
  <div class="fl"></div> 
  <div class="clr"></div><!-- This element stops float from going to unintended elements --> 
</div>
```

This is ideally how you would position floated elements for cross browser support.

If reworking your markup isn't doable, you could try adding empty elements, with a `clear: both;` style, as the LAST SIBLING of floated elements.  So...taking your ul#secondNav as an example you could try this...

```
<ul id="secondNav">
  <li class="stuff"></li>
  <li class="stuff"></li>
  <li class="stuff"></li>
  <li style="clear: both;"><!-- Leave empty --></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I tried your last suggestion (...adding empty elements) and also tried adding `<div class="clr"></div>` right after the `container` class,  but that didn't solve the problem :(  can you plz think of any other way of accomplishing this?!

Comment: When you tried adding the div, did you also change the other elements to divs?  Divs aren't permitted content for ul.  So you would have to change both the ul and the child li elements to divs.

Comment: when i tried adding the `<div class="clr">` this is how i did it: <div id="header">  <div class="container"> .......<div class="clearBoth"></div><!--/.clearBoth--> </div><!--/.container --> 
</div><!--/#header -->  (Sorry, it's messy)

Comment: sorry, it's:  <div id="header"> <div class="container"> .......</div><!--/.container --> <div class="clearBoth"></div><!--/.clearBoth--></div><!--/#header -->